# How do I see how long I've been playing a particular hero?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm trying to figure out how long it takes to bring a character from 1-60 using the most optimal gear in the game.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to see how long I've been playing that hero for.

I know that for dead hardcore heroes listed in the Hall of Fallen Heroes, it shows the total time played, but how can I find total playing time with heroes that aren't dead yet?

Comment: Can't remember exactly where, but I seem to remember there being some extended stats view you can get to which shows how long you've been playing, along with a number of other informative bits of info...

Comment: @agent86 would be great if you can figure out where to get that view

Comment: I know there's a place to see total time played for a *class*, but I don't know if there's a total playtime on a per-character basis.

Comment: @Samjus good find, that's exactly what I wanted

Comment: @spartacus No problemo. Eyes of a hawk haha